# Solving quadratic equation $x^2-(k+1)x+k+1=0$ using quadratic formula

Tags: quadratics

### Disclaimer

I am new here so please mind how i have  executed this question. Feel free to comment on how to improve as i have read on “how to ask a good question”.

### Problem

I am having trouble answering this quadratic equation that my teacher at school used. I do not know where she had gotten this equation from.

Equation:
$$x^2-(k+1)x+k+1=0$$

Quadratic Formula:
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

My teacher got the final answer of $$x=\frac{(k+1)\pm k}{2}$$

I have asked my teacher on how to solve for x, however she said she won’t show the steps on how to solve this problem because it is ***simply too easy***. When i don’t understand how she got that answer.

### My working out

I have simply found my coefficients for x^2 and x, and my constant is k+1.

**a= 1** 
**b= (-k-1)** 
**c= k+1**

I am not sure if c actually equals k+1
Then I put them into the quadratic formula.

$$x=\frac{-(-k-1)\pm\sqrt{(-k-1)^2-4\times 1\times k+1}}{2\times 1}$$

Which then i get

$$x=\frac{(k+1)\pm\sqrt{k^2+1-4k-3}}{2}$$

I don’t know what to do next and if my answer can be correct, ***please help***.

Comment: Your teacher's answer is wrong and you have also made  mistake as pointed out in Toby Mak's answer.

Comment: If the teacher was right then $c$ must equal $1/2\cdot(k+1/2)$ due to Vieta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that $(-k-1)^2 \ne (-k)^2 + (-1)^2$. Where's the middle term?

You should have instead:

$$x=\frac{-(-k-1)\pm\sqrt{k^2+2k+1-\color{red}{4(k+1)}}}{2\times 1}$$
$$x=\frac{k+1\pm\sqrt{k^2-2k-3}}{2}$$

which does not simplify to your teacher's answer (as others have described).

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just another thing: you can click the tick (below the voting bar) to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) an answer. You don't have to accept now as there may be more answers in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the problem is not that easy after all. What your teacher *believes* is the solution is obviously wrong. After all, she suggests that $\frac12$ is one of the solutions, but 
$$ (\tfrac12)^2-(k+1)\tfrac12+k+1\ne 0$$

Comment: I was going crazy trying to get what she got. Thank you 

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ $(-k-1)^2 = (k+1)^2 =k^2 +2k+1.$

Comment: My mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of parameters are correct so you should get that $$\sf{x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{(k+1)\pm\sqrt\Delta}{2}}$$ where $\sf{\Delta=(-(k+1))^2-4(1)(k+1)=k^2+2k+1-4k-4=k^2-2k-3\ne k^2}$ so your teacher is wrong nonetheless.

Comment: @farruhota Thanks, I misread the minus signs in the OP's attempt.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help! 

Answer (score 1):

It is often a good idea to check the results by numerical examples.

If we set $k=1$, the equation becomes $x^2-x+1=0$, and your teacher's answer would be

$$x=\frac12\ !?$$

Now,

$$\frac{(k+1)\pm\sqrt{(k+1)^2-4(k+1)}}2=\frac{(k+1)\pm\sqrt{(k+1)(k-3)}}2$$

yields

$$\frac{1\pm i\sqrt3}2,$$ which works.

A simpler check is possible with $k=3$, giving $x=2$ indeed a solution of $x^2-4x+4=0$.

---

A check is not a proof, but it can increase your trust in a solution.

Comment: Thank you! I will do that next time before writing the answer my teacher has given me.

Comment: @SophiaSerrato: and after providing your own !